# Mail not send using PHPMailer from production server

Tags: php, phpmailer

**Is it necessary to turn on the less secure apps of my gmail account?** why I'm asking this means am trying to do send email in production server.
I used PHPHMailer and I tried without turn on my less secure apps of my email account, I get error like below

SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14

SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

what can I do?

Comment: You need to enable less secure apps .

Comment: Read the docs before asking in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable less secure apps if you would use SMTP with classic authentication mechanisms.

Otherwise you can use XOAUTH2 with PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2

Comment: No you don't. You can use XOAUTH2 authentication, which doesn't need less secure apps to be enabled.